# How to convert the returned interface variable by a method to object?

Tags: c#, c++, interface, dllimport

I am using a c# wrapper, in the c++ library, the called function returns a pointer to the class object.
In the c# wrapper, if I call that method it returns an interface variable.
That interface variable is null, so I am unable gets the values.
How should I handle that interface variable in order to get values.
Anyone please help me.

In the below code we have ROOTNET.Interface.NTH1F it is an interface, where ROOTNET.NTH1F is a class

```
using ROOTNET.Utility;
using ROOTNET.Interface;

NTH1F g = new ROOTNET.NTH1F("g", "background removal", doubleArrayX.Length - 1,    
    doubleArrayX);

g.SetContent(doubleArrayY);
g.GetXaxis().SetRange(xmin, xmax);

ROOTNET.NTH1F bkg = new ROOTNET.NTH1F(g);
bkg.Reset();

bkg.Add(g.ShowBackground(80, ""));
```

In the above Im expecting the backgroung removed values to be saved in bkg but bkg contains all zeros, can you please help me in getting background removed values of g into bkg.

Where as the code of `ShowBackground(int niter, string option)` method is

```
public unsafe virtual NTH1 ShowBackground (int niter, string option)
{
    NetStringToConstCPP netStringToConstCPP = null;
    NetStringToConstCPP netStringToConstCPP2 = new NetStringToConstCPP (option);
    NTH1 bestObject;
    try
    {
        netStringToConstCPP = netStringToConstCPP2;
        int num = *(int*)this._instance + 912;
        bestObject = ROOTObjectServices.GetBestObject<NTH1> (calli ((), this._instance, niter, netStringToConstCPP.op_Implicit (), *num));
    }
    catch
    {
        ((IDisposable)netStringToConstCPP).Dispose ();
        throw;
    }
    ((IDisposable)netStringToConstCPP).Dispose ();
    return bestObject;
}
```

Comment: I disagree with the close vote. This is _specific_, but not _local_. I can see this question being asked again by a future visitor, even if not likely. Please provide a reason for voting to close questions, in the future.

Comment: Anyone one please help me, sorry if I didn't ask the question properly, I am a learner.

Comment: Please provide some examples of what you've tried. Code, that is.

Comment: The problem with poorly asked question is not, that we nastily won't answer, but that we won't understand, what you are asking for and what the circumstances are. You should spend more time on asking the question to ensure, that everyone will correctly understand, what the problem is.

Comment: Its OK, my straight forward question is, there is a c++ dll and it has a function whose return type is a pointer to class object, now I am using a .net wrapper to that c++ dll, in this wrapper the replica of that method returns an interface variable, so whenever I call that method a null value is coming into my hands, this is my problem brother

Comment: It is a problem when a method returns null when it's not supposed to.  Read the documentation to find out what might make it return null.  What's your *question*?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat a pointer value returned from C++ as an interface (unless it's a COM interface, I guess). C++ and C# classes and interfaces may (and mostly probably do) have different low-level structures, so you cannot simply cast one onto another.

The only way is to write another wrapper around C++ class returned by your library. It should look more less like that:

C++/DLL:

```
__declspec(dllexport) void * ReturnInstance()
{
    return new MyClass();
}

__declspec(dllexport) void MyClass_CallMethod(MyClass * instance)
{
    instance->Method();
}
```

C#:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
private static extern IntPtr ReturnInstance();

class MyClassWrapper
{
     private IntPtr instance;

     [DllImport("MyDll.dll")]
     private static extern void MyClass_CallMethod(IntPtr instance);

     public MyClassWrapper(IntPtr newInstance)
     {
         instance = newInstance;
     }

     public void Method()
     {
         MyClass_CallMethod(instance);
     }
}

// (...)

IntPtr myClassInstance = ReturnInstance();
MyClassWrapper wrapper = new MyClassWrapper(myClassInstance);
wrapper.Method();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but here neither I have the source code of the c++ dll nor the c# wrapper dll

Comment: If C++ returns a class or interface, then surely you should have at least the header file. If so, you can wrap that DLL in your own DLL, write a C# wrapper for your C++ wrapper and that should work. However, make sure, that you have enough understanding of DLL and P/Invoke mechanisms prior to pulling off this project, because it seems, that it overwhelms you a little judging from what I read.